# Is there a way to search music used in any video through YouTube API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Youtube recently started adding the music used in a video to the bottom of the description. It uses a different format than the original description, and I am wondering if there is a way to access this through the Youtube API. Under this part of the description, it shows the song, with a link to a Youtube video of that song, and the artist, license, etc.

After searching through the Youtube developer/API forums there doesn't seem to be formal support for descriptions at all, let alone this specific music section of the description.
I am new to APIs in general, so I might be looking at this the wrong way. Maybe I don't need to have a formal "key" and can isolate this music description through writing my own program?

Thank you for the help.

An example of what this looks like is attached (from the video CANDYLAND by William Strobeck https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yk1cLKpzHck )

[image]

Comment: The `Music in this video` section under the Youtube's web UI video description is not accessible via [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint under the normal video description provided by [`snippet.description`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.description) property. As far as I know, there is no API that provides that info (that under the section  `Music in this video`), but let's wait for other SO users that know better.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. It would be frustrating if this is true.

Comment: [I have answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74652266) the same question on StackOverflow, let me know if it doesn't fit your needs.